# How to replace by a function in word vsto?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I am using this function to replace in word and it works fine when replacing all

```
foreach (Range rang in WordApp.ActiveDocument.Words)
        {
            if (Regex.Match(rang.Text, @"\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?").Success)
                rang.Text = rang.Text.ReplaceNewText(Options);
        }
```

But the problem is when I want to perform the replacement in the selected text only, it replaces only one result and not all results
this My Code To Replace in Selectet Text:

```
    foreach (Range rang in WordApp.Selection.Words)
        {
            if (Regex.Match(rang.Text, @"\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?").Success)
                rang.Text = rang.Text.ReplaceNewText(Options);
        }
```

Comment: Is there a chance the `Selection` is changed when you do replacements?

Comment: Yes, I think so, how do I keep the selection so that it does not change